# Homomorphism of groups $f: G \rightarrow H$ where $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Define a homomorphism as $f: G \rightarrow H$ where $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$

$G=\mathbb R$ and $H=\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$

Checking that it is a homomorphism:

$f(xy)=e^{2\pi i x y}=(e^{2πix})^y=f(x)^y$ this is therefore not a homomorphism.

Is my method suitable here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $G$ is here $(\Bbb R,+)$, so that you need to verify
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)f(y).
$$
But this is true. Note that $H=(\Bbb C^{\times},\cdot)$.

Comment: Yes of course. I forgot $\mathbb R$ wasn't a group under multiplication